# What is the use of right_docked_overlay in android SystemUI?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-source

While working on the AOSP, I found something like the below line.

`<include layout="@layout/right_docked_overlay" />`

My issue is, in lock screen there is an emergency button which is shown with alignment towards right side of the screen. I want it to be placed to the center of the screen. I found from the layout xml file that the above mentioned line is present before the emergency button block.

```
<include layout="@layout/right_docked_overlay" />
        <com.android.keyguard.EmergencyButton
            android:id="@+id/notification_keyguard_emergency_call_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/kg_emergency_call_label"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="@dimen/kg_status_line_font_size"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:drawablePadding="8dip"
            android:textAllCaps="@bool/kg_use_all_caps"
            android:visibility="gone"
            androidprv:locateAtNonSecureView="true" />
```

I want to know the functionality of the 'right_docked_overlay'. 
I found a right_docked_overlay.xml in layout which is an empty stub.

```
<!-- empty stub -->
<merge />
```

I didnt understand how its working here.

The path for the xml files is as follows: 
*/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/*

Please help me understanding.

Thank you